# Ionic 2 rc0: create a custom http service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm moving from an ES6 project (beta11) to a new project with rc0 and I'm having some problems to rewrite a custom http service I had.

In my providers/ folder I have customhttp.ts:

```
import {Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import {Http, Headers} from "@angular/http";
import {RequestOptions, XHRBackend} from '@angular/http';
@Injectable()

export class CustomHttp extends Http {
  constructor(xhrBackend: XHRBackend, requestOptions: RequestOptions) {
    super(xhrBackend, requestOptions);
   }
  //some other methods, which override the defaults from Http
}
```

in my app.mmdule.ts I have imported this and added as a provider

```
import {CustomHttp} from '../providers/customhttp';
...

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [CustomHttp]
})
```

in a page I'm trying to use it

```
import {CustomHttp } from '../../providers/customhttp';
export class CheckAccess {
  constructor(private customHttp: CustomHttp)
}
```

the .ts are compiled but the browser outputs

*error_handler.js:45EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./CheckAccess class CheckAccess_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by: No provider for ConnectionBackend!*

I can't find out what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help?

Comment: the problem is with class **ConnectionBackend**. Add this class to providers and you should be well!

Answer (score 1):

Import XHRBackend and RequestOptions in your app module and check by setting below as providers :

```
providers :[
 {
  provide: CustomHttp,
  useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) => {
     return new CustomHttp(backend, defaultOptions);
  },
  deps: [ XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
  }
 ]
```

Comment: Hi! I've tried this, but the problems persists :-/ still can't find provider for ConnectionBackend